# how to get value from previous view in Yii

Tags: php, yii

I'm not sure how to describe my question. First I added a button at my CCGridview:

```
array(
    'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    'template' => '{view}{update}{delete}{upload_image}',
    'buttons' => array(
        'upload_image' => array(
        'label' => 'upload foto',
        'url' => 'Yii::app()->createUrl("/image/create",
        array("product_id" => $data->product_id))',
        ),
    ),
),
```

when I clicked it will bring me to the /image/create view which has a product_id value. For example on that gridview I clicked record number 7, so the url would be:

> (webApp)/index.php/image/create?product_id=7

Since it rendering a partial _form so the form has the attribute according to the image table which has this attributes: id, title, filename, product_id.

So the view will be something like:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'title'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'title',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>45)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'title'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'filename'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->fileField($model,'filename',array('size'=>45,'maxlength'=>45)); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'filename'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'product_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'product_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'product_id'); ?>
</div>

<div class="row buttons">
    <?php echo CHtml::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? 'Create' : 'Save'); ?>
</div>
```

My question is, how do we use the value from the url which I mentioned before is 7 (../create?product_id=7) into the product_id attribute without have to type it at provided textField?

In other word I will remove this from the view:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'product_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->textField($model,'product_id'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->error($model,'product_id'); ?>
</div>
```

But when i submitted, the form the value (7) should have been passed/saved at product_id field.

Added:
My controller actionCreate is

```
//...
public function actionCreate()
{
            $dir = Yii::app()->basePath . '/../productimages/';
            $uploaded = false;
            $model=new Image();

            if(isset($_POST['Image']))
            {
                $model->attributes=$_POST['Image'];
                $tempSave=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'filename');
                if($model->validate())
                {
                    $uploaded = $tempSave->saveAs($dir.'/'.$tempSave->getName());
                    $this->redirect(array('/products/index'));
                }
            }
            $this->render('index', array(
                'model' => $model,
                'uploaded' => $uploaded,
                'dir' => $dir,
            ));
}
```

That's it. Many thanks..

Comment: Show us the controller action, as that is where you need to initalize the variable.

Comment: @Pentium10 There I've added my controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify your controller this way:

```
if(isset($_POST['Image']))
{
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Image'];
        $tempSave=CUploadedFile::getInstance($model,'filename');
        if($model->validate())
        {
            $uploaded = $tempSave->saveAs($dir.'/'.$tempSave->getName());
            $this->redirect(array('/products/index'));
        }
} else {
   //initialize defaults
   $model->product_id=intval($_GET['product_id']);
}
```